# template function definition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, clang++

I have this code:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(const T1& a, const T2& b) -> decltype(viennacl::linalg::prod(a, b)) {
    return viennacl::linalg::prod(a, b);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(const T1& a, const T2& b) -> decltype(prod(a, b)) {
    return prod(a, b);
}
```

`viennacl::linalg::prod` and `prod` are two different functions (may also be templated).

I thought that if some template function definition can not be used for some types, the compiler would just silently ignore it and try another definition. Is that wrong?

Clang 3.3 compiles fine and all works as expected. GCC 4.9 however throws this error:

```
mathutils.hpp:77:6: error: redefinition of 'template<class T1, class T2> decltype (prod(a, b)) operator*(const T1&, const T2&)'
 auto operator*(const T1& a, const T2& b) -> decltype(prod(a, b)) {
      ^
mathutils.hpp:72:6: note: 'template<class T1, class T2> decltype (viennacl::linalg::prod(a, b)) operator*(const T1&, const T2&)' previously declared here
 auto operator*(const T1& a, const T2& b) -> decltype(viennacl::linalg::prod(a, b)) {
      ^
```

So, which compiler is wrong?

And what would be the possible workarounds? (If it is not clear what I want to do: I want to implement `operator*` so that it uses either `viennacl::linalg::prod` or `prod`, depending on which one of those provide an implementation.)

---

Small self-contained test case:

```
namespace X {
    template<typename T> struct Mat{};
    template<typename T> struct MatExpr {};

    template<typename T>
    MatExpr<T> prod(Mat<T> const& A, Mat<T> const& B) { return MatExpr<T>(); }
};

struct Mat2 {};

template<typename T>
X::Mat<T> prod(X::Mat<T> const& A, Mat2 const& B) { return X::Mat<T>(); }


template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(const T1& a, const T2& b) -> decltype(X::prod(a, b)) {
    return X::prod(a, b);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(const T1& a, const T2& b) -> decltype(prod(a, b)) {
    return prod(a, b);
}



int main() {}
```

I reported that upstream as a bug in GCC [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59509).

Comment: For the same T1 and T2, what is the exact type given by the two decltypes? If they are the same, I'd expect it give a message like you have.

Comment: `prod` and `viennacl::linalg::prod` will never work both, it's always either the first or the latter; it's even that the decltype is never defined in both cases. Also, the error doesn't happen at the usage, the error happens already when the compiler parses the definitions.

Comment: Any change you construct an SSCCE?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will come along later on and quote the relevant passage in the standard on whether gcc is right or wrong. In the meantime, here's a workaround you can try:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator *(const T1 &a, 
                const T2 &b) -> decltype(::prod<typename T1::value_type>(a, b))
```

What I did above is to explicitly specify the template argument so it knows exactly what `prod` it should instantiate. Another subtlety was that I had to globally qualify it explicitly so ADL doesn't get in the way. Without this the compiler will see that `a` is a type in `namespace X` and it'll end up considering both `X::prod` and `::prod` which would be ambiguous.

Lastly, a minor change to `X::Mat` so we can refer to its type `T`:

```
namespace X
{
  template<typename T> struct Mat { typedef T value_type; };
  // ...
```

Here's a [**working test example**](http://ideone.com/coDGye).